# Как получить сообщение из двух слов discord.py?

Tags: discord.py

Делаю бота для повторения сообщения которое написал пользователь но бот повторяет только первое слово вот код:

```
async def say(ctx,text):
await ctx.message.delete()
await ctx.send(text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что по умолчанию в качестве аргумента `text` дискорд передает только первое слово. Чтобы получить весь текст после команды можно воспользоваться оператором `*`:

```py
async def say(ctx, *, text):
    . . .
```

Подробнее можно **[почитать здесь.](https://github.com/denisnumb/discord-py-guide/blob/main/discord-py.md#%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD-%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82)**

Comment: Сработало, благодарю

Comment: не подскажите как это сделать?